# In postgres, is "analyze <table>" a non-blocking statement?

Tags: postgresql

I did some basic search, but can't find the answer.

I am wondering if "analyze " is an unblocking statement. What I mean "unblocking" is the statement returns, but the analyze is still running in the backend.

The reason I am asking is I have seen code (JAVA, using jdbc) to issue:

```
statement.executeUpdate("analyze " + tableName + ";")
```

then query on pg_lock to see if the table has ShareUpdateExclusiveLock, only when the table does not has the lock, the code continues.

so analyze is unblocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `ANALYZE` statement won't return until statistics calculation is complete. I am not aware of any SQL statement in PostgreSQL that works asynchronously like you describe.

The code you read seems misguided; perhaps cargo cult programming.